# Having trouble "TypeError: String Indeces must be an integer"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm decently new to Python3 and I'm having trouble with this for a Project Euler question. Please don't give me the code I want to understand why this is wrong. BTW a palindrome is a number that reads the same way backwards for example 98089 or 6759576.

I'm not sure what to do I think it is the holder variable that's not working as a integer.

```
numberString = 0
holder = 0
partOne = 0
partTwo = 0
counter = 0
num = 0

def isPalindrome(number):

    if number % 2 == 0: #EVEN
        numberString = str(number)
        holder = len(numberString)
        holder = holder // 2
        holder = int(holder)
        partTwo = numberString[-(holder),-1]
        partOne = numberString[0,(holder - 1)]
        if partOne == partTwo:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif number % 2 != 0:  #ODD
        numberString = str(number)
        holder = len(numberString) // 2
        partTwo = numberString[-(holder),-1]
        partOne = numberString[0, (holder - 1)]
        if partOne == PartTwo:
            return True 
        else:
            return False

for first in range(100,1000):
    for second in range(100,1000):
        num = first * second
        if isPalindrome(num) == True:
            print(num,'is a palindrome.')
```

I expect to have example = palindrome for all the possible palindromes that are products of 3 digit numbers.

I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    if isPalindrome(num) == True:
  File "main.py", line 15, in isPalindrome
    partTwo = numberString[-(holder),-1]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: This isn't an integer: `[g[-(holder), -1]` that's two values there. Did you mean: `g[-(holder)-1]` without the comma?

Comment: there is a typo in your code you have `PartTwo` instead of `partTwo` in one of your conditionals. Have answered your question below though

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing is all messed up, take this example & try it,

```
test_str = "123456"
print(test_str[:-3])
print(test_str[3:])
print(test_str[2:4])
```

The concept is called [slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-about-strings-in-python-set-2/). The strings are 1D arrays the `:` operator allows you to cut up strings.

Comment: But what I was trying to do was split the string into 2 parts where one part had the first part of the string in it while the other one had the second part, isn't that how I would do it?

Comment: no the way you do it is how I've done it in the answer. numberString is a 1D array so will only accept 1 index. I'd edit the answer for a better description